# Set image to background image for view controller and maintain when rotated on ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, uiinterfaceorientation

I am trying to place an image as a background for viewcontroller in an ipad application. I set this using

```
UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Pilot@2x~ipad.png"];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: background];
            imageView.frame = self.view.bounds;
            [self.view addSubview: imageView];
            [self.view sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
```

This works fine for portrait mode, but when I rotate it to landscape mode there's a blank space where the picture doesn't fill. My idea based on other similar posts was to have a new picture that is called when the rotation get's changed and I tried this

```
 {    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

        if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)){

            UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Pilot@2x~ipad.png"];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: background];
            imageView.frame = self.view.bounds;
            [self.view addSubview: imageView];
            [self.view sendSubviewToBack:imageView];



        } else  if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)){

            UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed: @"PilotLandscape@2x~ipad.png"];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: background];
            imageView.frame = self.view.bounds;
            [self.view addSubview: imageView];
            [self.view sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
        }}
```

Which resulted in the same thing. Any ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated!

Comment: when u rotate the device landscape to portrait or portrait to landscape is

Comment: when you rotate the device from landscape to portrait or portrait to landscape is called?
if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)){
}else  if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
{}

Comment: Are you autolayout in your app?

Comment: Add two different size of images on your project. 1. For portrait view-768X1024(retina-1536X2048), 2. For Landscape view- 1024X768(retina-2048X1536). Now, change the background image(For Portrait-image No.1 and For Landscape-image No.2) when you rotate your screen.

Answer (score 0):

Check view's autosizing settings, try to NSLog view's coordinates, pay attention to uiimageview's UIViewContentModeScale property. Why don't you simply add imageview to your storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

**Working Code :**

```
@interface SOViewController (){
    UIImageView *imageView;
}

@end

-(void)initialOrientationHandling
{
    //[self.view removeFromSuperview];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        [[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){

        imageView.frame = self.view.bounds;

        [self.view addSubview: imageView];
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:imageView];


    }else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait ||
              [[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){

        imageView.frame = self.view.bounds;

        [self.view addSubview: imageView];
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:imageView];

    }
    else if([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation]== UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp){
        if(self.view.frame.size.height < 900){

        }else{

        }
    }
}

-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{

    [self initialOrientationHandling];
}
```

Obviously the image will be distorted if not highly pixled. I recommand you use different for different rotations.

Comment: So in the if I just set one picture and in the else if another? And none of this in the view did load method correct?

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT:

First create two image, one is landscape view size and another for portrait.

Initialize  imageview

```
              var   Imgview = UIImageView()
```

In  viewWillAppear method ,  it change image when view load and also when rotate.

```
     override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    Imgview.frame = self.view.frame


    Imgview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    Imgview.clipsToBounds = true
    view.addSubview(Imgview)
         // get notification while rotating

      NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "rotate", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil
    )


         }
```

Function rotate for set image,it is called in notification center.

```
                 func rotate()
              {

if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
{
    Imgview.frame = self.view.frame
    Imgview.image = UIImage(named: "landscapeSizeimage.png")

    self.view.sendSubviewToBack(Imgview)


   }

   if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
{
    Imgview.frame = self.view.frame
    Imgview.image = UIImage(named: "PortraitSizeimage.png")

    self.view.sendSubviewToBack(Imgview)


   }}
```

This worked for me.Hope it helps someone.And i dont know may be it create more imageviews so instead of bringtosubview we can remove imageview as your wish .